# How to measure distance between two moving objects?

Tags: measurement, distance, resolution

I wanted to ask if anyone knows a way to measure the distance between two moving objects (actually one is fixed and one moving)?
Can I place on one of them a transmitter and on the second one a receptor and know in real time the distance between the two? The range I'm looking in is about 0 - 0.5 meters and resolution of about 0.5 cm.
Can anyone recommend on a way of doing it?

Comment: How fast will the moving object be going?

Answer (score 1):

Sound is a relatively easy phenomena to use to measure distances because it is quite slow.

There are many answers which you could find on this site, e.g [Why sound wave is the best choice for many location detectors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131531/why-sound-wave-is-the-best-choice-for-many-location-detectors/131535)

This explains some  of the issues around using electromagnetic radiation [High precision trilateration in a small space and without ultrasound](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130078/high-precision-trilateration-in-a-small-space-and-without-ultrasound/130095)